# Embedded Python Segfaults

Tags: c++, python, multithreading, segmentation-fault, embedding

My multi-threaded app segfaults on a call to `PyImport_ImportModule("my_module")`.

The BT will be posted at the bottom.

Some background:

1. My app creates multiple instances of many derived C++ classes and runs the base class's `Run()` function which uses a virtual method to determine what to do.
2. One derived class uses a Python Class, `Grasp_Behavior`(class) in `grasp_behavior`(module)
3. After extensive reading I have used the Python API to achieve (2) (exerpts below)
4. I generate 2 instances of said class, and run them in "parallel" (python interpr doesn't really run parallel)
5. I attempt to generate another instance of said class, segfault at `PyImport_ImportModule`

My thoughts are that perhaps I cannot import a module twice in the same interpreter.  But I can't figure out how to check it.  I assume I need to see if `grasp_behavior` is in a dictionary but I don't know which one, perhaps I get `__main__` module's dictionary?

But I might be wrong, any advice would be incredibly helpful!

In the constructor:

```
//Check if Python is Initialized, otherwise initialize it
if(!Py_IsInitialized())
{
    std::cout << "[GraspBehavior] InitPython: Initializing the Python Interpreter" << std::endl;
    Py_Initialize();
    PyEval_InitThreads(); //Initialize Python thread ability
    PyEval_ReleaseLock(); //Release the implicit lock on the Python GIL
}

// --- Handle Imports ----

PyObject * pModule = PyImport_ImportModule("grasp_behavior");
if(pModule == NULL)
{
    std::cout << "[GraspBehavior] InitPython: Unable to import grasp_behavior module: ";
    PyErr_Print();
}
 // --- Get our Class Pointer From the Module ...
PyObject * pClass = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "Grasp_Behavior");
if(pClass == NULL)
{
    std::cout << "[GraspBehavior] InitPython: Unable to get Class from Module: ";
    PyErr_Print();
}
Py_DECREF(pModule); //clean up, this is a new reference

behavior_instance_ = PyObject_Call(pClass, pArguments_Tuple, pArguments_Dict);
if(behavior_instance_ == NULL)
{
    std::cout << "[GraspBehavior] InitPython: Couldn't generate instance: ";
    PyErr_Print();
}
Py_DECREF(pArguments_Tuple);
Py_DECREF(pArguments_Dict);
Py_DECREF(pClass);
```

Here, note that I only initialize the Python interpreter if it has not been initialized.  I assume it gets initialized for the entire process.

In the `Run()` method (ran from a boost thread):

```
std::cout << "[GraspBehavior] PerformBehavior: Acquiring Python GIL Lock ..." << std::endl;
PyGILState_STATE py_gilstate;
py_gilstate = PyGILState_Ensure();

/* ---- Perform Behavior Below ----- */

std::vector<std::pair<double, double> > desired_body_offsets;
//desired_body_offsets.push_back( std::pair<double, double>(0.6, 0));
PyObject * base_positions = GetTrialBasePositions(my_env_, desired_body_offsets);

PyObject * grasps = EvaluateBasePositions(my_env_, base_positions);

//Did we get any grasps? What do we do with them? [TODO]
if(grasps != NULL)
{
    std::cout << grasps->ob_type->tp_name << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Number of grasps: " << PyList_Size(grasps) << std::endl;
    successful_ = true;
}

/* --------------------------------- */

std::cout << "[GraspBehavior] PerformBehavior: Releasing Python GIL Lock ..." << std::endl;
PyGILState_Release(py_gilstate);
```

Here, I have gone with `PyGILState` lock.  I read for a while and it seemed the some of the articles that many people are link use an older style of locking in Python ... perhaps I may have to switch this.

---

Backtrace:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fffee9c4330 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fffee9c4330 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0
#1  0x00007fffee99ff09 in PyEval_GetGlobals ()
   from /usr/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0
#2  0x00007fffee9bd993 in PyImport_Import () from /usr/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0
#3  0x00007fffee9bdbec in PyImport_ImportModule ()
   from /usr/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0
#4  0x000000000042d6f0 in GraspBehavior::InitPython (this=0x7948690)
    at grasp_behavior.cpp:241
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you must not call any Python API functions when the GIL is released (except the GIL acquiring calls).

This code will crash:

```
PyEval_ReleaseLock();

PyObject * pModule = PyImport_ImportModule("grasp_behavior");
```

Release the GIL after you're done setting up and then re-acquire as needed (in your `Run()`).

Also, `PyEval_ReleaseLock` is deprecated, you should use `PyEval_SaveThread` in this case instead.

```
PyThreadState* tstate = PyEval_SaveThread();
```

This will save the thread state and release the GIL.

Then, right before you start finalizing the interpreter, do this:

```
PyEval_RestoreThread(tstate);
```

passing the return value of the `PyEval_SaveThread` call.

In `Run()`, you should use `PyGILState_Ensure` and `PyGILState_Release`, as you do now, but you should think about C++ exceptions. Right now `PyGILState_Release` will not be called if `Run()` throws.

One nice property of the `PyGILState` calls is that you can use them no matter if the GIL is acquired or not and they will do the right thing, unlike older APIs.

Also, you should initialize the interpreter once at startup in the main thread (before other threads are started) and finalize after shutting down all threads but the main one.

Comment: Hey yak, thank you so much for the response!  I just wanted to clear up somethings and get your input:

1) Note that I only release the lock ONCE, when Py_InitThreads is called.  I read that that activates the lock.  I could not find any specific examples of releasing the implicit lock your way, could you rephrase it for my application (described next).

(2) My classes are instantiated in the main thread.  Their run method is called in boost threads (using boost::bind).  The run thread calls Py_Ensure and Py_ReleaseGIL. Then exits to the main thread where more classes are instantiated.

Comment: Also, your comment on exceptions is spot on, this is not my problem right now but I am sure it would have caught me later.  Thank you so much for bringing that to my attention.  Lastly, I do not finalize the interpreter because I do not know if other classes in my program are still using it.  I leave that for the destructor at the end of the process itself.

Comment: I am home now btw, I can't wait to try these suggestions tomorrow though.

Comment: `PyEval_InitThreads` creates (and acquires) the GIL. It should be called from the main thread. After you're done with all setup `Py*` calls, you should release the GIL by calling `PyEval_SaveThread` (ignore the return value if you're not doing cleanup on exit). You can start your threads before that if you want, the `PyGILState_Ensure` calls in their `Run` methods will block until the main thread releases the GIL. When that happens, one of the blocked threads will continue (and that thread will own the GIL now) until it calls `PyGILState_Release` at which point another thread may enter.

Comment: So instead of calling PyEval_ReleaseLock inside the if statement, call PyEval_SaveThread?  Note that the statements inside the if block are only executed once.  I may have multiple classes import and instantiate Python modules.  (Lastly note that my main thread interacts through a base Class interface, and these python calls are done in a derived class.  I hope one day to remove the Python Classes completely and implement them in C++)  So I guess my question is, should I be calling PyEval_SaveThread at the end of every call in the constructor even though they're all done in the main thread?

Comment: Of course, the main thread is no different at that point and also has to use `PyGILState_Ensure` before calling any Python APIs. Keep in mind that this doesn't mean that there will be no two `Run` methods running simultaneously. If you start executing Python code in one of the threads, the interpreter will repeatedly release and re-acquire the GIL letting other threads to run. Python IO calls like `file.read()` also release the GIL. For best results, never keep the GIL acquired for any longer than needed.

Comment: Ah, this is starting to make sense.  I will add `PYGILState_Ensure` and Release inside the constructor call itself as well.  All that's left is the implicit lock from the `Py_InitThreads`.  I am assuming I do that with the `PyEval_SaveThread` instead of the `PyEval_ReleaseLock`.  Also, is there a certain place you read all this?  I have scoured that Python API (it's not bad once you get used to it) but have not picked any of this up.

Comment: Yes, replace `PyEval_ReleaseLock` with `PyEval_SaveThread`. What I didn't realize is that this is in the constructor of your "classes" so this will run multiple times. This means you have to call `PyGILState_Ensure` right before the `PyImport_ImportModule("grasp_behavior")` call (and `PyGILState_Release` when you're done). For the first call, it will initialize Python, create the GIL (InitThreads), release it (SaveThread), re-acquire it (Ensure), do the stuff (ImportModule, etc.) and release it again (Release) at which point `Run` will be free to acquire it using `PyGILState_Ensure`.

Comment: For future calls it will start with acquiring the GIL (PyGILState_Ensure). In fact, I would move the initializing code (the `if`-block) to `main` or some other function run at the startup of the entire program.

Comment: Sadly, I cannot do that.  The goal is to have this as a plugin architecture at some point.  The python calls are only a temporary fill in to use code written by a colleague.  Yak, you've been amazingly helpful!  I'll try all this out tmrw, but I have a good feeling you nailed it.

Comment: We use Python embedded in a multithreaded C++ application at my work. I'm just speaking from my experience. When I had my own questions I usually referred to the official documentation and Python C source. For example, here are the docs explaining threads and GIL: http://docs.python.org/c-api/init.html#thread-state-and-the-global-interpreter-lock

Answer (score 1):

Does Boost provide a moral equivalent to the `pthread_once()` function that allows some initialization task to be run exactly once, no matter how many threads try to run it simultaneously? If this were my problem to debug I'd try to guard `PyImport_ImportModule` against multiple calls in multiple threads and using a standard tool for that would be my first attempt.

Comment: That's a great idea, I will add a static flag to the class tomorrow.